# How do the super power upgrades that work differently for each element, work for the 'Explosive' element (Element of Destruction Pack DLC)?

Tags: saints-row-iv

The [Element of Destruction Pack DLC](http://www.saintsrow.com/news/detail/article/264365/two_new_dlc_packs) introduces the 'Explosive' element for all super powers: Explosive Chain Blast, Telekinetic Time Bomb, Airstrike Stomp and Explosive Buff.

There are [upgrades](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Powers#Upgrades) that affect all elements and may work differently for each element. Since the game currently does not have a description of what these upgrades do for the 'Explosive' element, I am wondering what their effects are for it.

The [upgrades](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Powers#Upgrades) are the ff:

- Blast

  - Damage
  - Explosive Deaths (Since the Explosive element already explodes affected enemies upon their deaths - what does this upgrade do for it?)
- Telekinesis

  - Hold Cost (How much energy is consumed?)
  - Power Up 1 and 2
- Stomp

  - Damage
  - Duration
- Buff

  - Team Player  (Will nearby homies become immune or take less damage from explosions, or will they have a chance of firing explosive bullets?)

For the damage, duration and power up upgrades, what increases and how exactly does it increase?

Answer (score 1):

Blast

- all NORMAL human/alien on hit range exploded(work for drivers to).

Telekinesis

- all NORMAL human/alien caught become grenade(don't hold too long).

Stomp

- all NORMAL human/alien on stomp range became firework, and goes down like Air Support from SR3(this is overpowered -_-)

Buff

- all NORMAL human/alien near you will explode after some time.

Genki Girls, Warden, Assasination Target, Bosses and Super Enemies  won't be affected by explosion element.

Comment: I'm talking about the specific upgrades that I listed in my question - (explosive deaths, team player, etc). Know how those are affected?